# Able to run Pytest from PyCharm but not through Command Line

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

I am trying this on Ubuntu. So when I run PyTest from PyCharm it worked perfectly but when I tried to run the same command I am getting different errors.
Surely I am not building my Command correctly.

So here is what it looks like in PyCharm

```
target = /some_path/test_xxx.py    
options= --server ### -s --browser firefox --html=report.html
```

And below are what I have tried on shell

```
lab-automation:~/My_Folder$ py.test /<some_path>/test_XXX.py --server ### -s --browser firefox --html=report.html 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/py.test", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/config.py", line 48, in main
    config.pluginmanager.check_pending()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/vendored_packages/pluggy.py", line 490, in check_pending
    (name, hookimpl.plugin))
_pytest.vendored_packages.pluggy.PluginValidationError: unknown hook 'pytest_html' in plugin <module 'pytest_suites.conftest' from '/<some_path>/conftest.pyc'>
```

I have also tried this

```
py.test --server ### -s --browser firefox --html=report.html /<some_path>/test_XXX.py
usage: py.test [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
py.test: error: unrecognized arguments: --server --browser firefox
```

So in this case it looks like its not able read my conftest file

Comment: I was able to solve it. I was using `pytest-html` plugin. so when I needed to use it I was doing `import pytest_html`.
The correct way of doing this is

`pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('html')`

Though it still doesn't explain why it was working with PyCharm.
May be PyCharm inovkes PyTest differently.

Answer (score 1):

yeah I think PyTest don't have a server argument. 
probably it`s missing some plugin

you can see the args list by typing

```
py.test --help
```

check it out the plugin list https://pytest.org/dev/plugins_index/index.html that you can use.